# GraphQL query argument that accepts key value pairs?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'd like to pass the following key:value pairs to a GraphQL query. I imagine it working something like this, but have been unable to find a way to achieve this.

```
query myPortfolio {
  portfolio(holdings: {"btc": 0.12, "ltc": 12.1}) {
    # ...
  }
}
```

I attempted to create a special type and pass it as an array, but this failed compilation.

```
type Holding {
  coin: String!
  amount: Float!
}

type Query {  
  portfolio(holdings: [Holding!]): Portfolio!
}
```

`Error: The type of Query.portfolio(holdings:) must be Input Type but got: [Holding!].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the message says, the arguments needs to be of `input` type. Change your schema to something like

```
type Holding {
  coin: String!
  amount: Float!
}

input HoldingInput{
  coin: String!
  amount: Float!
}

type Query {  
  portfolio(holdings: [HoldingInput!]): Portfolio!
}
```